# Show Dialog window in BroadCast Receiver

Tags: android, dialog, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I have an app that in a special time show the notifier . it's work well. But  I want to show Dialog window too. In dialog window part there is an error. 
Could someone help me that what should I do?
thanks

this is my code

```
private void showNotification(Context context) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle(
            "do your work"  );
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(100, mBuilder.build());

    //---------here there is an error 
     Dialog dialog= new Dialog( context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dialog.setTitle("This is your time");
        dialog.show();
        //----------------
}
```

this code is in broadCastReceiver class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

generally you can not call dialogue from your receiver. Instead of that you can call an activity from broadcast receiver. The activity can be displayed as dialogue in android through windows manager. Thats it.. Hope it helps!!

Comment: Tanks. This is a good way but I have an error too  with intent. this is my code    startActivity(new Intent(Receiver.this,DialogActivity.class));  and the error is   The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type Receiver

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(context, yourclass.clas  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);   This is how you have to call intent from receiever.